# Insert commas after the first and second words in each line using Python?

Tags: python, regex, csv, text, nlp

I have a .txt file and I need to convert it to CSV. 
This is the code I'm using to convert the file:

```
import pandas as pd

wb = pd.read_csv('12.txt', encoding='utf-8', delimiter = '،', header = None)

wb.to_csv('12.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig', index = None)
```

The problem is, in each line, the first and second words need to be in separate cells, however they are not separated by commas :

```
This is an, example, to show, you
The second line, is, the, same
My file contains, thousands of, sentences
```

As shown in the example, only the first and second words of each line are supposed to be in separate cells (Other cells might contain more than one word!).
How can I add commas ONLY after the first and second words in each line using Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use `str.replace` here:

```
wb['col'] = wb['col'].str.replace('^(\S+) (\S+)', '\1, \2,')
```

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't I define 'col' before this line?

Comment: I assume that you already have a column `col`, and you just want to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for each word to be in a different cell, you could apply the following to each line:

```
line = "This is an, example, to, show, you"

split = line.split(",")

x = [item for sublist in [k.split(" ") for k in s] for item in sublist]
y = list(filter(lambda x: x != "", x))

output: ['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'to', 'show', 'you']
```